How do I disable SPF checks for local networks?
When configuring postfix, how do I require SPF but only if it's not from a local network sender? I tried the following:
smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,
    check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf,
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname

...and I thought that in this order, permit_networks would match before the SPF policy check and allow sending. However, that isn't the case, and SPF fails and rejects any mails from the local network. I'm not sure how to fix this issue.
If relevant, I tried this using Postfix 3.9.

It should work like this. The only way for it to get to policy service is for the client that was not authenticated and is not in mynetworks. Attach more: at least, the mynetworks value and your relevant logs. Also, there are other smtpd_*_restrictions; maybe, one of these blocks. It's always advisable to report what the tag description suggests, postconf -n, from the start.

Thanks so much for the response! I checked with smtpd -vv and the problem indeed seems to be that mynetworks by default doesn't include the full 172.16.0.0/12 range, with the mail coming from docker. You wouldn't happen to know why mynetworks doesn't default to all private addresses by default? I changed it in my config now, but I'm wondering why postfix omits some addresses and if this change will break something else for me.

It doesn't, and it shouldn't. In fact, the optimal value for it is empty, and to require everything to authenticate.

Ah I see, interesting! So it's meant to be manually configured rather than default to all local network addresses, I didn't know that. Thanks so much for pointing that out.

As discovered by @nikita-kipriyanov the above approach was fundamentally somewhat correct, the sender was just from a local network address that postfix's mynetworks doesn't contain by default which is why permit_mynetworks didnt apply and SPF was checked anyway despite it being sent from the local network. So the fix was to add 172.16.0.0/12 to mynetworks in /etc/postfix/main.cf. I mistakingly assumed mynetworks defaults to just all local network addresses but it doesn't, it seems like it needs to be manually set beyond just loopback interfaces.
